# Visual Studio autocomplete event handler with lambda format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda, event-handling, intellisense

I'm on VS2012 and want to use the lambda format for event handling, however VS does autocomplete with the tab key whenever you type an event subscrition via +=, e.g.:

VS autocompleted with a reference to a function an inserts the function:

```
txtTitle.TextChanged += txtTitle_TextChanged;

void txtTitle_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ....
}
```

Is there any way to force autocomplete with Lambda format of:

```
txtTitle.TextChanged += (object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    ....
}
```

Its a huge pain to have to copy and paste from the autocompleted non-lambda to the tighter lambda format.

Comment: You could use types of lambda parameters, because compiler infer that. `Resharper` suggests you lambda format of handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a code snippet, I have one for creating Lambda events.

here is the snippet if you want to try (just save as *whatever*.snippet) and import in VS (Tools -> Code Snippet Manager)

Snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>SnippetFile1</Title>
      <Author>sa_ddam213</Author>
      <Description>
      </Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>le</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>s</ID>
          <ToolTip>s</ToolTip>
          <Default>s</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>e</ID>
          <ToolTip>e</ToolTip>
          <Default>e</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp" Kind="method body"><![CDATA[($s$,$e$) => { };]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Then to use just type the **eventname += le Tab**

Example

Loaded += le Tab

Result

```
Loaded += (s, e) => { };
```

Comment: WOW!  That's amazing... i'm hobbiest and had no idea about snippets.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
this.txtTitle.TextChanged += (s, e) => {};
```

Comment: Yes - i'm aware of the format but i don't want to copy and paste.  I'm wonder if you can configure Visual Studio to autocomplete (via tab or something) into this format.